# Decouple Three Partial Differential Equations

Tags: analysis

How to decouple this system so I can get three decoupled equations of the following forms: $q_1$= function of $q_1$, $q_2$= function of $q_2$ and $p$= function of $p$.
\begin{eqnarray}
&&q_{1t}=(q_{1,xx}+3pq_{1})_x,\\
&&q_{2t}=(q_{2,xx}+3pq_{2})_x,\\
&&p_t=(p_{xx}+\frac{3}{2}p^2+a_1q_1^2+a_2q_2^2)_x
\end{eqnarray}
Any ideas to separate these equations in terms of $q_1, q_2$, and $p$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)? Do you have any reason to believe that such a decoupling is possible?